# React Array.fliter() does not show result on iphone, safari or chrome, but run perfectly on PC

Tags: reactjs, filter, mobile-browser

Here is my function code

```
 const searchArray = stats.filter((dish) =>
    dish.dishName.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
  );
```

```
       <div className="input-group-sm stock mb-3 m-auto">
          <input
            type="search"
            className="form-control m-auto mb-4 mt-4 searchWindow"
            placeholder="Sök maträtten"
            aria-label="Sök..."
            aria-describedby="button-addon2"
            onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
            value={searchTerm}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul className="searchResult">
            <li>{searchArray.map(CreateRecord)}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

and CSS

```
.searchResult {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* Add the ability to scroll */
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    /* IE and Edge */
    scrollbar-width: none;
    /* Firefox */
}
.searchResult::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
```

Runs perfectly on PC, but on iphone, when i input a text on searchbar, all results disappear.
Any one know why?